# Why isn't OpenGL used in the majority of today's blockbuster games?

Tags: opengl, directx

My friend came up with this simple question: Why do the "big" titles of today almost all use DirectX, and not OpenGL?

Are there specific technical reasons, or is it all Microsoft's marketing?

Comment: It's very subjective question. But I believe it's Microsoft's marketing.

Answer (score 3):

Probably to make porting to XBox 360 easier.

Comment: And automatically leaving out Mac, Linux and all other non-MS platforms as potential targets?

Comment: @CatInTheBox:  From a purely anecdotal point of view, it appears to me that most recent big-name games get released on PC, Xbox 360, PS3, and sometimes Wii.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you got your figures from, but last time I checked most games used OpenGL for their graphics stuff. <s>Nintendo Wii, Playstation 2, 3 and the portables</s> (due to comments ignore that), MacOS X, iOS (iPhone, iPad), Android they all use OpenGL (in some variant). So any game running on one of these actually is using OpenGL. In Windows DirectX is majorly used because… Honestly I don't know why.

EDIT: Even without being used on Nintendo and in most Playstation 2 & 3 games, there are still iOS and Android devices, which are a huge market, where OpenGL is the 3D API to be used.

Comment: According to wikipedia, *"It is a myth that variants of OpenGL are used on Nintendo and Sony platforms, as they have developed their own libraries. The PlayStation 3 game console has an OpenGL implementation, but it remains unused by most developers due to performance issues."*

Answer (score 0):

Datenwolf is right in that most games are probably OpenGL just by sheer number, a claim that is very hard to substantiate. In the windows world, Microsoft did a great job at marketing DirectX over OpenGL. It helps that every game for years would say you need the latest DirectX on windows. After that, it's just momentum. If a development company wants to find the API that they can find programmers for, then they need to find the platform that has the biggest backing. Programmers learn to use DirectX for windows because of the amount of windows game developers that use directX. "I'm unhappy because I eat and I eat because I'm unhappy, it's a vicious cycle" hahaD